# Examples of functions $h$ for which asymptotic $\pi(x+h(x))-\pi(x) \sim \frac{h(x)}{\log x} \ (x \to \infty)$ fails

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

By a 1985 result of Maier, the asymptotic
$$\pi(x+h(x))-\pi(x) \sim \frac{h(x)}{\log x} \ (x \to \infty)$$
fails if $h(x)$ is any power of $\log x$.  Are there known examples of functions $h(x) = o(x)$ with $(\log x)^a = O(h(x))$ for all $a>0$ for which the asymptotic above fails?  If so, what is the best such result known, in the sense that the order of growth of $h(x)$ is largest?  For example, is it known to fail for $h(x) = e^{(\log \log x)^t}$ for some $t >1$?

Reference: H. Maier, Primes in short intervals, Michigan Math. J. 32 (1985) 221-225.

Comment: Variant now posted to Overflow, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453662/on-the-asymptotic-pixhx-pix-sim-frachx-log-x-x-to-infty

Answer (score 4):

There are certainly not known examples, as far as I know. I think it's reasonable to conjecture that there will be no larger examples. The conjectures for the ratio
$$
\frac{\pi(x+(\log x)^A)-\pi(x)}{(\log x)^A/\log x}
$$
is that its lim sup $M(A)$ and its lim inf $m(A)$ both approach $1$ as $A\to\infty$, which to me suggests that the corresponding limit will equal $1$ as soon as "$A$" goes to infinity with $x$, that is, as soon as $h(x)$ is not $(\log x)^{O(1)}$.

Comment: Thank you.  Do you have a reference for this conjecture?